# New column indicating if row is the first instance of the value for the Entity ID using SQL instead of DAX

Tags: oracle, plsql

I currently have a column that is created using the following DAX formula (a calculating language used by platforms such as Power BI) which indicates if the listed activity is the first one ever for that `Entity ID`. Below is my DAX script if it helps at all:

```
// "Declares column name"
First Time Activity = 

// "if the column 'Timestamp' is equal to..."
if('Activity Table'[Timestamp]=

// "...is equal to the earliest Timestamp for that Entity ID and Activity Name"
CALCULATE(min('Activity Table'[Timestamp]),
    filter('Activity Table',
        'Activity Table'[Entity ID] = earlier('Activity Table'[Entity ID]) && 
        'Activity Table'[Activity Name] = earlier('Activity Table'[Activity Name])
            )
    )

// "...then return a 1. If not, then return a blank/null"
,1,BLANK())
```

[image: Example]

But I need this now to be a column made in PL SQL rather than in DAX. Any help on the SQL script would be much appreciated since I'm fairly novice at SQL.

Thanks

Comment: what is DAX  ...?

Comment: @OldProgrammer it's like a calculating language used by some programs like Power BI but instead of manipulating the data in the Power BI platform I need to do it in PL SQL / Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need a column. you can write your query as :

```
Select a
       ,decode(activity_date
               ,MIN(activity_date) over (partition by activity_id)
               ,'Y'
               ,'N') first_record_indicator
 From activity_table a
```

But, if you table is too huge to actually query like this everytime, you can create a column named first_record_indicator and populate it in "BEFORE INSERT" trigger.

e.g. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php

Comment: A before insert trigger would NOT be suitable here. That would require selecting from the table the trigger is on to see if the event already existed. Doing so however would raise a ORA-04091:table xxx is mutating  exception.